# WPF expand a style

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles

I have a listbox that is created with this code:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}"
         SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
</ListBox>
```

Now I want to apply a contextmenue to each item.
How can I use my current style but with a context menue. Can i do something like a derivation from that style? Would be really great if you would know something to solve that problem... :)

Comment: I'm really not positive what you're asking. You want to add a context menu to each item in the listbox? Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To derive from a style you can use the basedon property, for instance:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the `Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle` style yourself, you should be able to add something like adding another setter to it:

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ContextMenu>
            ...
        </ContextMenu>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: it is not my style it is contained in a dll file